# openni don't like xtion pro live

Tags: ros, slam, navigation, rgbdslam-freiburg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

can xtion pro live be ran on rgbdslam ?

I have my rgbdslam installed and
sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-openni-launch

and I ran >roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch
the message returned as below

No matching device found.... waiting for devices. Reason:  creating depth generator failed. Reason: USB interface is not supported!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64258/openni-don%27t-like-xtion-pro-live/) by [Benzwr](https://answers.ros.org/users/4977/benzwr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-06-03

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-06-04**:
Do you have a USB 3.0 interface, by any chance?

**Comment by [Faizan A.](https://answers.ros.org/users/4585/faizan-a./) on 2013-06-05**:
I faced a similar problem. The new sensors of xtion pro live work with openni2. whereas openni_launch is based on openni. You can use https://github.com/ros-drivers/openni2_launch.git with catkin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably too late to answer, I have tried running rgbdslam with Asus Xtion Pro and it works far better that Kinect. As mentioned above, Asus Xtion Pro uses openni2 libraries. You have the latest repository [here](https://github.com/occipital/OpenNI2.git). You can find help in using Asus Xtion pro in rgbdslam from my blog [here](https://roboram.wordpress.com/asus-xtion-pro-live-ubuntu-14-04-installation/)(Ubuntu depth camera test) and [here](https://roboram.wordpress.com/2016/04/19/asus-xtion-pro-live-ros-installation/)(ROS Installation).

---

Originally posted by [R@m](https://answers.ros.org/users/25832/r@m/) with karma: 98 on 2016-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0